Issue with JDBC Data Retrieval in Apache NiFi 2.0.0-M4 Using SqreamDB
I am experiencing an issue while using Apache NiFi 2.0.0-M4 with SqreamDB. Although the JDBC connection is successfully established and verified, executing a simple query (SELECT 1 AS test) results in the message:

contains 1 records; transferring to 'success'

without retrieving any actual data. Additionally, the ExecuteSQL processor remains active and does not complete, preventing the FlowFile from moving to the 'success' relationship.
Environment Details:

NiFi Version: 2.0.0-M4
JDBC Driver Version: sqream-jdbc-5.3.1.jar
Operating System: Oracle Linux 7.9
JDBC Connection String:jdbc:Sqream://[IP]:[Port]/nbdata;cluster=true;service=user_svc;fetchSize=1;

Steps Taken:

Verified JDBC connection successfully.
Executed SELECT 1 AS test query.
Observed contains 1 records; transferring to 'success' without data retrieval.
ExecuteSQL processor remains active and does not complete.
Attempted changing fetchSize to 100 with no resolution.
Checked NiFi logs for errors, but found none related to this issue.

